# Using Osmosis to extract a map from a larger pbf file using a bounding box

Tags: python, matplotlib, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have a large data set of lats and lons.  mplleaflet was overwhelmed.  After determining my BBox, OpenStreetMap yielded a "too many nodes..." error.  And recomened planet.osm.  Based on posted advice, I down loaded a state from Geofabrik.org, and then installed Java and Osmosis in effort to extract my area from the xxx.osm.pbf file from Geofabrik.  I think it's ready to go, but although Osmosis https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box makes it sound easy to extract what I need, the example doesn't make any sense.  I have a bounding box.  The closest example I find on the Osmosis site is here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage.  I can't understand how this relates to the xx.osm.pbf file or what the "use CONIN$ instead" is referring to.  Any help is much appreciated. Seems this will be fun once I'm able to do it.

[image]

Comment: Osmosis helps you extract and filter OSM data from one format to the other. What format are you looking for as an output?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I can use .png  I am plotting a scatter of latitude and longitude points on the map in matplotlib.  I was under the impression that Osmosis would help me select a bounding box from the larger map file.   My box is too big to get directly from openstreetmap.  Any help with instructions is appreciated.  I saw a blog about Folium Maps, I was going to try that next since I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Osmosis will help you reduce the size of the data with the bounding box, however the output format will have to be one that osmosis supports, like pbf (.osm.pbf) or xml (.osm). Then you need to find a way to read that output file.

Comment: I assumed there would be clear instructions on how to convert the file to a different format, but the instructions on how to extract a specific bounding box ae not clear, or I can't understand them.   I can't understand why openstreetmap is so popular if it is this complicated to get the area you want.  Is Osmosis not the most efficient, and straight forward tool to use?  It seems not, as I still don't have any answer to the original question, how do you extract the bbox in windows 10?  I appreciate your 'heads up' about the file conversion.  Thank you.